# How to show data on bar graph from SQL database in android studio

Tags: java, android, bar-chart

I have a bar graph and data present in MYSQL database, I can fetch it and show it on textview but the problem is that how can I show it on bar graph. I've marks data of six subjects of multiple users, the user list is in recycler view, when i click any user it shows details of the user, **now i want to show marks of the selected user on bargraph**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Try this using MPAndroidChart library:

`public void mPlotWeeklyBarGraph
(ArrayList yValBarOne) {

```
    BarDataSet barDataSet1 = new BarDataSet(yValBarOne, "Week One");
    barDataSet1.setColor(Color.RED);
    float gs = 0.1f;
    float bs = 0.02f;
    float bw = 0.43f;
    BarData barData = new BarData(barDataSet1);
    barData.setDrawValues(false);
    barChart.setData(barData);
    barData.setBarWidth(bw);
    barChart.groupBars(0, gs, bs);
    barData.setValueFormatter(new LargeValueFormatter());
    XAxis xAxis = barChart.getXAxis();
    WeekOne = new ArrayList<>();
    WeekOne.add("Mon");
    WeekOne.add("Tue");
    WeekOne.add("Wed");
    WeekOne.add("Thu");
    WeekOne.add("Fri");
    WeekOne.add("Sat");
    WeekOne.add("Sun");
    xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(WeekOne));
    barChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
    barChart.invalidate();
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a powerful android library which make it simple to show charts and graphs in you app

https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart

Comment: Thanks Sir! but i've already added the library and its working, My questions is how to show data from database into the bar graph? BTW thank you.